# Clearing system notification

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-notifications

I am trying to implement this plugin [Phonegap system notification](https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin). I am reading two Rss feeds and displaying it to the user as a Status bar notification. Once the Notifications has been displayed to the user and the user clicks on the notification, he is taken to the app but I am not able to clear the notifications from the status bar. Could you please suggest me a way to clear these notifications by looking at my code.
How can I call **navigator.systemNotification.cancelNotification()** when the user clicks on the statusbar notification.

**notification.js**

```
google.load("feeds", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
var rss1old = '',
    rss1new = '',
    rss2old ='',
    rss2new ='',

    getRss = function (url, callback) {
        (url) && (function (url) {
            var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(url);

            feed.load(function (result) {
                (!result.error && callback) && (callback(result.feed.entries[0].title));
            });
        }(url));
    };

setInterval(function () {
    getRss(
        'http://yofreesamples.com/category/free-coupons/feed/?type=rss',
        function (title) {
            rss1new = title;
            if(rss1old !== rss1new) {
                rss1old = rss1new;
                navigator.systemNotification.onBackground();
                navigator.systemNotification.updateNotification(rss1new,1);
                navigator.notification.beep(1);
                navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);
            }

        }
    );
}, 5000);

setInterval(function () {
    getRss(
        'http://yofreesamples.com/category/real-freebies/feed/?type=rss',
        function (title) {
            rss2new = title;
            if(rss2old !== rss2new) {
                rss2old = rss2new;
                navigator.systemNotification.onBackground();
                navigator.systemNotification.updateNotification(rss2new,1);
                navigator.notification.beep(1);
                navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);  
            }

        }
    );
}, 6000);
});
```

**SystemNotification.js -> Included from the plugin**

```
function SystemNotification() {
}

SystemNotification.prototype.notificationEnabled = false;

SystemNotification.prototype.newCount = 0; //to keep track of multiple notifications events

SystemNotification.prototype.enableNotification = function () {
    this.notificationEnabled = true;
};

SystemNotification.prototype.disableNotification = function () {
    this.notificationEnabled = false;
};

SystemNotification.prototype.onBackground = function () {
    this.enableNotification();
};

SystemNotification.prototype.onForeground = function () {
    this.disableNotification();
};

SystemNotification.prototype.createStatusBarNotification = function (contentTitle, contentText, tickerText) {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "createStatusBarNotification", [contentTitle, contentText, tickerText]);
};

SystemNotification.prototype.updateNotification = function (contentText, tickerText, number) {
    this.newCount++;
    var contentTitle = this.newCount + "RssFeeds";
    if (this.newCount === 1) {
        this.createStatusBarNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);
    } else {
        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "updateNotification", [contentTitle, contentText, this.newCount]);
        this.showTickerText(tickerText);  //optional
    }
};

SystemNotification.prototype.cancelNotification = function (contentText) {
    this.newCount--;
    if (this.newCount === 0) {
        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "cancelNotification", []);
    }
    else {
    //updating the notification
        var contentTitle = "my title";
        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "updateNotification", [contentTitle, contentText, this.newCount]);
    }
};

SystemNotification.prototype.showTickerText = function (tickerText) {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "showTickerText", [tickerText]);
};

SystemNotification.prototype.touch = function () {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "touch", []);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function () {
    if (typeof(navigator.systemNotification) == "undefined") {
        navigator.systemNotification = new SystemNotification();
        navigator.systemNotification.touch();  //this ensures that the plugin is added when phonegap kicks off
    }
});
```

**Systemnotification.Java -> Included from the plugin**

```
package com.yfs.project;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;

public class SystemNotification extends Plugin {

    final int notif_ID = 1234;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification note;
    PendingIntent contentIntent;

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId)
    {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        String result = "";

        try {
            if (action.equals("createStatusBarNotification")) {
                this.createStatusBarNotification(args.getString(0), args.getString(1), args.getString(2));
            }
            else if (action.equals("updateNotification")) {
                this.updateNotification(args.getString(0), args.getString(1), args.getInt(2));
            }
            else if (action.equals("cancelNotification")) {
                this.cancelNotification();
            }
            else if (action.equals("showTickerText")) {
                this.showTickerText(args.getString(0));
            }
            return new PluginResult(status, result);
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    private void updateNotification(String contentTitle, String contentText, int number)
    {
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this.ctx, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        note.number = number;
        notificationManager.notify(notif_ID,note);
    }

    private void createStatusBarNotification(String contentTitle, String contentText, String tickerText)
    {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        note = new Notification(R.drawable.rss, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
    //change the icon

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.ctx, Yfs.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent = notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(this.ctx, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        note.number = 1;  //Just created notification so number=1. Remove this line if you dont want numbers

        notificationManager.notify(notif_ID,note);
    }

    private void cancelNotification()
    {
        notificationManager.cancel(notif_ID);
    }

    private void showTickerText(String tickerText)
    {
        note.tickerText = tickerText;
        notificationManager.notify(notif_ID,note);
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.webView.loadUrl("javascript:navigator.systemNotification.onBackground();");
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.webView.loadUrl("javascript:navigator.systemNotification.onForeground();");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On android, you'll need to set the flag `AUTO_CANCEL`

Where you have this

```
note = new Notification(R.drawable.rss, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
```

Add this line right under

```
note.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Otra!! Appreciate the help !!